# How to retrieve direction of movement in highway with Google Maps API

Tags: gps

my problem is this: given a GPS location (that indicates the position on the car on a generic highway) I want to retrieve the direction of movement (north or south) to understand which side I am.

On Google Maps Api documentation's page I don't found any request that return me this information.

What I would do is calculate the distance between my position and the next service area (the GPS coordinates of service areas are in my personal DB) that I'll found during my travel.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I know that the question was made a long time ago. However, I'm facing the same problem and can't extract the solution from the answers.

I have the points that compose the highway, so I have its geometry. But, how can I define if I'm going to one side of the highway, or to the other (considering that the highway is not oneway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Google Maps API; it's a generic question.

A single set of coordinates found by GPS is just that: a location. You need to get another location a short time afterwards, and the difference will allow you to calculate the direction and speed of travel.

Comment: Your answer is partially right. The reference system of the gps coordinates is not the same of the highway. So, with only two gps points (without any other reference point) it's impossible calculate the direction on the highway.

Comment: @Fry: It's true that the GPS coordinate may not show as being on the highway, but that's a mapping error. The difference between two GPS readings will always get you a direction, so if they are close enough together that direction can be taken as a direction along the highway. How close together they are depends on many variables including the device itself and the ability to process the data (and probably more).